# Bot following a grid in reverse order

Tags: c, path-finding

I am supposed to write a program in C only. It's code for a grid follower.

I have defined a co-ordinate system of the grid (0-5,0-5). Also the bot orientations (+y,-y,+x,-x) and positions are defined. (I would welcome tips on how to write good code for this.)

Now as my bot moves through the grid and goes to some coordinate (x,y) in the grid through some path. Only 90 deg and 180 deg turns are allowed.

How can I reach (0,0), i.e. the starting point, traversing the same path? How can I reverse the orientations and give appropriate turning instructions using C code?

Comment: Um...the answer depends on how you choose to *get* there in the first place. If you moved in the horizontal direction then the vertical to get back on the same path would require moving in the vertical then the horizontal, no? So...

Comment: How does the bot move from one position to the next? Answer with **code** please!

Comment: well i am searching for a way to write the code for the forward direction as well... so that it would be easy to trace back.. any suggestions are welcome..

Comment: one way i thought was like define orientations as 'Y','y','X','x' to mean +y,-y and so on.. and turn by 'r' and 'l' 'r' for right, left(90 deg) and 180 deg rev..

Comment: and assign the new orientations by appropriately seeing the old orientation and the turn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be cleaned up quite a lot, but it should be a good framework to understand the concepts. All we're basically doing is saving every move, and then simply backtracking it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STEPS 256

enum CARDINAL_DIRECTIONS { N = 0, W, S, E };

struct _s_robot {
    int x;
    int y;
    int orientation;
    int step;
    int x_history[MAX_STEPS];
    int y_history[MAX_STEPS];
    int turn_history[MAX_STEPS];
} MY_LITTLE_ROBOT = {0, 0, 0, 0, {0}, {0}, {0}};

void robot_go() {
    switch(MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation) {
    case N:
        ++MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y;
        break;
    case W:
        --MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x;
        break;
    case S:
        --MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y;
        break;
    case E:
        ++MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x;
        break;
    }
    MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x_history[MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step] = MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x;
    MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y_history[MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step] = MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y;
    MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.turn_history[MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step] = MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation;
    ++MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step;
}

void robot_change_orientation(int _orientation) {
    MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation = _orientation;
}

void robot_reverse_orientation(int _orientation) {
    if (_orientation == N) MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation = S;
    else if (_orientation == W) MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation = E;
    else if (_orientation == S) MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation = N;
    else if (_orientation == E) MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation = W;
}

void robot_backtrack() {
    int i;
    printf("MY_LITTLE_ROBOT wants to turn around, currently at: %i, %i\n", MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x, MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y);
    robot_reverse_orientation(MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation);
    for (i = MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step-1; i >=  0; --i) {
        printf("Robot is @ %i, %i, with an orientation of: %i \n", MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x, MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y,  MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.orientation );
        robot_reverse_orientation(MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.turn_history[i]);
        robot_go();
    }
}

void dump_history() {
    int i;
    for (i = MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.step-1; i >=  0; --i) {
        printf("Robot is @ %i, %i, with an orientation of: %i \n", MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x_history[i], MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y_history[i],  MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.turn_history[i] );
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("***START: Robot is @ %i, %i\n", MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x, MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y);
    robot_go();
    robot_go();
    robot_go();
    robot_change_orientation(S);
    robot_go();
    robot_go();
    robot_change_orientation(W);
    robot_go();
    robot_go();
    robot_go();
    robot_change_orientation(N);
    robot_go();
    dump_history();
    robot_backtrack();
    printf("***FINISH: Robot is @ %i, %i\n", MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.x, MY_LITTLE_ROBOT.y);
    return 0;
}
```

To use the robot over and over again, you may have to reset all travel history after a backtrack, which should be somewhat trivial. I purposely avoided `malloc`s and other confusing aspects of making the program actually useful for the sake of verbosity and simplicity. Hopefully it helps.

I also assumed you didn't want a *true* path-finding algorithm (such as A*), because that's a different ballgame altogether.

Comment: @ david... thanks a lot... ! really nice code structure...(at least for a beginner like me! :P)